# Modal session requires modal window

Tags: cocoa, modal-dialog, cocoa-sheet

I'm trying to open a window like a sheet so that it appears down below the toolbar. I've used the O'Reilly tutorial to do this. However, I can get past this error: Modal session requires modal window.

The window loads as a window if I have "Visible At Launch" checked.

Whether it is checked or not I get the "Modal session requires modal window" error.

I have a Window.xib, ProgressModal.xib.

In the Window implementation file I use:

```
-(IBAction)loadProgress:(id)sender{
    [self progressStatus:progressWindow];
}

- (void)progressStatus:(NSWindow *)window {

    [NSApp beginSheet: window
       modalForWindow: mainWindow
        modalDelegate: nil
       didEndSelector: nil
          contextInfo: nil];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow: window];
    [NSApp endSheet: window];
    [window orderOut: self];

}

- (IBAction)cancelProgressScrollView:(id)sender {
    [NSApp stopModal];
}
```

I may have the ProgressModal.xib setup wrong. I have an NSObject in it that has "Window" as its class. All the connections are made through that.

But again, it loads the window just won't load it as a modal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated above, I dragged an object over in the progressModal window and made my connections through that. What I should have done was made the File's owner my Window class. Changing that fixed the problem.

I got this from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBkO6TD-fWA

Answer (score 3):

Put the following in the first line of your `progressStatus` method:

```
NSLog(@"%@", window);
```

If you see the log output is null, that's the reason why.

Steps to create a modal sheet using XIB:

1. Drag a panel to your MainMenu.xib
2. Add `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPanel *sheetPanel;` in your `AppDelegate.h` file
3. `@synthesize sheetPanel = _sheetPanel;` in the `AppDelegate.m` file
4. Link a New Referencing Outlet of the panel in the MainMenu.xib created in the step 1 to the sheetPanel property created in step 2.
5. Using following code to show the modal sheet:

   ```
   [NSApp beginSheet:_sheetPanel
      modalForWindow:_mainWindow
       modalDelegate:self
      didEndSelector:@selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
         contextInfo:nil];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I assumed you wanted a modal window.  If you want a sheet, don't use `runModalForWindow:` at all.

Try this:

```
[NSApp beginSheet: window
   modalForWindow: mainWindow
    modalDelegate: nil
   didEndSelector: nil
      contextInfo: nil];
```

It's a good idea to define a callback just in case you need it though; e.g.

```
[NSApp beginSheet: window
   modalForWindow: mainWindow
    modalDelegate: self
   didEndSelector: @selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
      contextInfo: nil];
```

Comment: I do want a modal. I just want it to animate in like a sheet under the toolbar. And I want to avoid the error, obviously. Are you saying that adding a @selector will fix it?

Comment: The same method (`beginSheet:...`) spawns windows with two possible behaviors: blocking one window, or the whole app.  If you set `modalForWindow:nil`, then `runModalForWindow:` is OK (followed immediately by `endSheet:`, `orderOut:` as you have) and `stopModal:` does end it; but that's not animated or under the toolbar.  If you *do* set `modalForWindow:mainWindow`, you *don't* use `runModalForWindow:` or `stopModal:` and the sheet is open asynchronously; something, somewhere (typically a button) calls `endSheet:` and `orderOut:` at an appropriate time.

Comment: Ignore my `@selector` suggestion for now; that tells you when the sheet has closed but you don't appear to need that information.

Comment: I deleted [NSApp runModalForWindow: window]; I deleted [NSApp endSheet: window]; I deleted [window orderOut: self]; I ran it again and got the same error: "Modal session requires modal window." It looks like your first "Try this:" section. It still doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, progressWindow is declared like this in the header file: IBOutlet NSWindow *progressWindow;

Comment: I switched to using this code:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html
I get the same error.
How should I declare "progressWindow?" I am doing it as 
IBOutlet NSWindow *progressWindow

Comment: I have used every tutorial on the internet and nothing works. All the tutorials leave the same thing out: None explain how to setup the NIB file. I am beginning to think that my NIB file is missing something. I've tried NSWindow and NSPanel. I even checked the "Document Modal" under NSPanel. Is the problem with my NIB file?